# 'cmd' - not able to get the `grunt` version

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have installed the grunt using this command : `npm install -g grunt-cli` after i installed i am trying to fetch the `grunt` version using this command :

`grunt --version` - But i am not getting any output. what is the issue here? do i require to set the `env` variable or something?

please help me.

Comment: Did you run `npm install -g grunt-cli` as admin?

Comment: I din't run as admin. since i have admin rights with me. still let me re-install

Comment: no, i am talking about grunt only.

Comment: Try running as admin then try `grunt --version`. [Docs](http://gruntjs.com/using-the-cli#version-v) show installation using `sudo`.

Comment: please post as answer. as a aditional info, how to use grunt for static html sites?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to install Grunt globally as admin. Grunt [docs](http://gruntjs.com/using-the-cli) recommend to use `sudo` when installing. This would be recommended for any Grunt or Gulp plugins you are installing globally. Run the same command `npm install -g grunt-cli` in admin command line then try `grunt --version` once more.

I'd recommend posting a separate question for the grunt processing as that involves much more functionality. A good example on a sample gruntfile can be found at [Sample Gruntfile](http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile) and includes processing js and html files for various tasks.

Let me know if that helps.

Thanks!